# Probability Curiosity

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$
  be i.i.d. random variables with $ E\left[X_{1}\right]=0$
  and $0<Var\left(X_{1}\right)=\sigma^{2}<\infty.$.

Let $ S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{n}$. Consider now $\lim_{n\to\infty}E\Big[ \frac{|{S_{n}}|}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\Big]$

To which theorem I have to appeal in order to bring the limit inside?

Comment: Inside of what? The expectation?

Comment: @Sasha. Yes, inside expectation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_n=|S_n|/(\sigma\sqrt{n})$, one knows that $T_n$ converges in distribution to the absolute value of a standard normal random variable hence, by [Skorokhod's representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), there exists some random variables $Z_n$ and $Z$ defined on a common probability space such that $Z$ is the absolute value of a standard normal, each $Z_n$ is distributed as $T_n$, and $Z_n\to Z$ almost surely.

Now, $(T_n)$ is bounded in $L^2$ hence $(Z_n)$ is bounded in $L^2$ hence $(Z_n)$ is uniformly integrable hence $Z_n\to Z$ in $L^1$, in particular $\mathbb E(T_n)=\mathbb E(Z_n)\to\mathbb E(Z)$.

Comment: do u use Skorohold's theorem in your proof, right? Great answer thanks. Thinker

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem).